# r.json() converts the data to native python datatypes and json.dumps() converts to str

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have been coping with an issue since yesterday. In my code I have to extract the data from a system with requests module of python and load that data to snowflake so that someone else from the company can connect the PowerBI to snowflake and use the data for reporting. Previously it was direct connection to the source system but now the data is increased in the source so it takes a lot of time to load that data so that's why loading data to our company's snowflake storage.

I'm having an issue with the requests module in python. I get the data from source. but there is some data which needs to be in proper json format (in double quotes). I have attached a sample data from the response.

`resp = requests.get(url, authorization) data = resp.content`
this above code returns the data into bytes format.

`resp = requests.get(url, authorization) data = resp.json()`
this code returns the data into the native format of the python's data types. I make dataframe with this data and this data to snowflake and connect with the powerbi, it gives the json format error because on snowflake data goes with single quotes. which is not a correct JSON format for powerbi.

I have also tried
`data = json.dumps(data)`
it converts the data to "" quotes but it converts the data to str, and if somehow I convert the data back to dictionary and lists with

`eval(data)`
it is again in single quotes.

Follwoing is the data set attached.

'data': [{
'name': 'alvin',
'age' : '20',
'addresses':[{ 'house' : '187',
'street' : 'lindsly',
'city' : 'abc',
'country' : 'netherlands'}],
'communications': [{ 'signaling' : True,
'confirm' : False,
'phone' : '0123456'},
{ 'signaling' : True,
'confirm' : True,
'phone' : '0945785'}
}],
'careDegree': 'NO',
'dob': '1911-11-01T09:00:00.000Z',
partnerIds': [{'asvTeamNumbers': [],
'onlineTherapyContract': [],
'_id': '6e31c',
'patientId': 'ZXWB8',
'extra': 'ID'}],
}]

total datasize is almost 13000 rows. Or if there is anyway I can flatten this data into columns without going into to too much time consumptions.

I tried apply() functions for flattening the data but then I don't see anything based on which I should merge the data frames.

```
pd.json_normalize(data['data'], record_path=["partnerIds"] , max_level =None).head()
```

Comment: Do you want the results as a json string or as a python dict?

Comment: @JonSG I get the results in python dict, but I want them to store in snowflake database as a proper json fromat. with "" qoutes.